# Sorting by most viewed

Tags: feature-request

I quite like the "people reached" metric on the profile page for stackexchange users, one thing that intrigues me is which of my questions that are reaching people (are they ones I'm proud of, ones that were simple one-liners to an easy question, etc...), I used to open answers that I suspected were on popular questions to see how many views each question had but that has now gotten worrisome with my having 200+ answers. This should be true for the average active user as well.

So, my feature request would be the request to sort out my answer history in terms of "view count". The metric already exists and I don't *think* it would be to hard to sort answers based on that metric. To specify, the option to sort by views would be near the red box here:

[image]

**Edit:** After a fruitful discussion with Martin in the comments below, the "people reached" metric is much more constrained that the view count on questions you've answered, but I assume that the algorithm for the "people reached" is break-able into a per-question basis that would make this feature-request feasible.

Using the existing data from only the raw viewcount on questions is not enough, since for example, you could answer a question after it has garnered most of its views but it would still rate as the most viewed answer in your list.

Comment: Someone who is reasonable competent at the Data Explorer could write down such a query pretty easily. (Unfortunately, I am *not* reasonable competent at the Data Explorer --- I just mumble about)

Comment: @mixedmath, I was thinking of that whilst writing the post, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about the Data Explorer to bring it up myself. :-)

Comment: @mixedmath It seems that some such queries [already exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=most+viewed+answers+site:data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MartinSleziak those are only updated once a month and isn't site-specific. My request was more for a daily updated sorting algorithm implemented in the user interface for site specific profiles. For example: my user ID returns blank in the query for some reason, perhaps because I've only just started using the site?

Comment: @Zain In fact, once a week. I do not know what you mean but *not site-specific*. You can select the site for which you run the query. In any case, I understand that this does not answer your feature request (which is why it is a comment and not an answer), but since both you and mixedmath mentioned that you were thinking about using SEDE, I thought it would be useful to let you know that some people have already tried something similar.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, it was useful, thank you very much! :-) - but for some reason, inputting my user ID returns a null result, your user ID seems to work just fine though. Oh well. :-)

Comment: @ZainPatel One of the queries worked for me with your UserId. Try this link: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/59366/my-most-viewed-answers-based-on-question-view-count?UserId=161779

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you! I've updated my post. :-)

Comment: Your last paragraph gives one of the reasons why [this statistic is meaningless](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244305/259867).

Comment: You are the most average active user I can think of @ZainPatel